# Centraliser of a maximal $k$-split torus of a reductive $k$-group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group defined over a field $k$, and let $S$ be a maximal $k$-split $k$-torus of $G$. Then the centraliser $\mathscr Z_{G}(S)$ is defined over $k$. In fact, it is a Levi $k$-subgroup of $G$.

Does one have $\mathscr Z_{G}(S)(k) = \mathscr Z_{G(k)}(S(k))$ for the groups of $k$-rational points?

Comment: Maybe it's over-kill, but do you know uni-rationality of reductive groups? Hence of $S$, so its rational points are (Zariski) dense, etc? What's your context?

Comment: As @paulgarrett [mentions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422031/centraliser-of-a-maximal-k-split-torus-of-a-reductive-k-group#comment1084427_422031), this is often but not always true.  For example, if $G = \operatorname{SL}_2$ and $k = \mathbb F_2$, then it fails.